# Ruby on Rails, form_for, paperclip, and mass-assignment of protected parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

I have been developing a rails app that uploads and processes images. Images, along with other string information is submitted via a form_for. I've been researching this topic for about 16 hours now and no solution has worked. Honestly it's like rails isn't even reading my code.

One Processmodel has many Assets, where an Asset is just a model to hold one image file. When creating processmodels, I can never access the asset, always recieving the cannot mass-assign attirbutes: assets_attributes

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: asset):
  app/controllers/process_controller.rb:20:in `new'
  app/controllers/process_controller.rb:20:in `create'
```

-
This form is used in new.html.erb

```
<%= semantic_form_for @processmodel, :url => { :action => 'create' }, :html => {     :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :batch, :as => :string, :name => "Batch" %>
    <%= f.input :batchset, :as => :string, :name => "Batchset" %>
    <%= f.input :numSlots, :as => :number, :name => "Number of slots" %>    
    <%= f.input :key, :as => :file, :name => "Key" %>   

    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :asset do |asset| %> 
        <%= asset.input :asset, :as => :file, :label => "Image" %>
    <% end %><br />

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

-

```
class Processmodel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :batch, 
                :batchset, :numSlots,
                :key,:assets_attributes

  attr_accessor :key_file_name

  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user  
  has_attached_file :key
  #    :url => Rails.root.join('/assets/readimages/:basename.:extension'),
  #    :path => Rails.root.join('/assets/readimages/:basename.:extension'),

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true

  . 
  . 
  .

end
```

-

```
require 'RMagick'
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :results_string, 
        :name, 
        :ambiguous_results, 
        :image 
    belongs_to :batch_element
    belongs_to :processmodel
    has_attached_file :image 
    validates_attachment_presence :image
end
```

-

```
class ProcessController < ApplicationController
def create
    @Processmodel = Processmodel.new(params[:processmodel])
    @Processmodel.save    
    all_img = Array.new(@processmodel.assets.all)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @processmodel.beginRead(...)
        redirect_to :action => 'results_main', :controller => 'results' 
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
   end
end 
end
```

-

```
def new
  @processmodel = Processmodel.new
  #5.times{@processmodel.assets.build}
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html #new.html.erb
end
end
```

Am requesting an ideas on how to fix this and get my app working.

Comment: try to add attr_accessible :key, in your Asset model class

Comment: Can you show your the view? (presumably `new.html.erb`)

Comment: The above yielded no result. Key is not a part of asset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your database migration. Run:

```
rails g migration AddIdToAsset processmodel_id:integer
rake db::migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You've called your attached file `:image` here:

```
has_attached_file :image
```

But you call it `:asset` in your view:

```
<%= asset.input :asset, :as => :file, :label => "Image" %>
```

To fix, just change this line to

```
<%= asset.input :image, :as => :file, :label => "Image" %>
```